# cpu over description with ganeti

Tags: cpu, virtualization, linux-kvm, xen

first of all happy new year every body :) I am planing a Ganeti cluster with 10-12 virtual machines, I assume the workload will be very low since its running in my home lab, so allocating one vcpu to each virtual machine will be fine. I have an Intel quad-core with hyper threading enabled, so I have 8 logical cpu's, 32GB ECC RDIMM. My question is it possible to have more virtual machines with each one vcpu assigned more than the 8 logical cpu's that I have? Does Ganeti support a specific ratio (3:1 or 4:1)? I may have up to 16 virtual machine? as I said the workload is very low.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganeti with KVM allows up to 4:1 ratio, depending on the VM's and worload. I already bought the supermicro MBD-X10SDV-6C+-TLN4F with HT, this should be sufficient for my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Some documentation backing this up would be *super awesome*. The system flagged is as poor quality (but meh, its a workable answer), and that would definitely be handy for people who're wondering where this information can be found